# signing a structure in windows and reading it in linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, encryption, signing

I have a structure such as follow:

```
struct mydata
{
    int a,
    int b,
 }
```

I want to fill it in Windows and then send it to somebody to read it in Linux. I am writing both applications.

The aim is that user in the middle should not be able to change the data, but he can read it.

The user may have access to source code of Linux code, but not windows application.

My questions are:

1- How can I do this? My first idea is to create a hash from structure, encrypt it with private/public key and send to user (in windows). On Linux decrypt it and check that has code match data. Is this the best solution?

2- What type of library I can use? The library should be available on windows and Linux.

3- Is there any sample code that give me a starting point?

### Edit 1

The question is more about how to make sure that data is not tampered with as it is transferred between windows system and Linux one via file copy (file on a sd card or via email). So the question is more about how to make sure that data is tamper proof and not how to transfer it.

### Edit 2

I need to send the data to Linux system as a structure written into a file ( a binary file that when read by application on Linux, mapped into a structure and then used by application). So effectively I have it as a structure on windows, then I need to sign it and write it into a file and send to Linux computer. On Linux computer, application need to read it, check that it is not tampered and then use the data.

My question is how to sign the data.

Comment: Just to be sure. Is your question only about encryption/signature or also about how to make 2 machines communicate ?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Via Network and sockets

2.) POSIX socket API, similar for windows and linux, forget about encription in the first place

3.) http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: Why are you advising the OP to "forget about encription in the first place" ?

Comment: Becaus he/she does not know the basics. Adding encryption on top of the communication would be the next step (at least if you do not want session management, automatic key exchange etc.)

Comment: @knivil: Why do you think the OP doesn't know the basics of network communication? The question is how to sign the data, and "forget about that" isn't an answer.

Comment: It starts with "i want ... " not with "i have .. ".

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edited question. I am interested to know how to make data tampered proof and not how to transfer it.

Comment: Your edits question is as bad as your unedited. If it is a file why did you mention "struct" or c++ programming at all? At least crypto++ is a library you want to look at.

Comment: Thanks. More data added.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find a way to encode/decode your structure content into a byte array which may be platform agnostic (in term of endianness, 32/64 bits, string encoding...). You should take a closer look to [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). ASN.1 aims to provide an unambiguous and a software & hardware independent data encoding. There is multiple libraries providing ASN.1 encoder and decoder such as [OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108234/432589) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/users/uses_open.html) (even if there are not always well documented)

For tamper resistance, there is a cryptographic standard for message exchange called CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax, aka PKCS#7) specified in [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-9). This standard defines multiple message types providing tamper resistance feature: signed-data and authenticated-data. OpenSSL only supports signed-data messages signed-data requires public key cryptography. Authenticated-data is easier to use since it only requires to share a commons secret key. Even if I do not know a library which supports authenticated-data.